# setting class path in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I used to run eclipse on my laptop. I have installed and used Secunia PSI application in order to update the apps, but once I done that I cannot run Eclipse.

This is what I have:
[image]

I set the PATH to the directory which contains javaw.exe app. The path at the PATH variable is the same as of CLASSPATH variable.
So, what are your resolutions? Done, it works now. I just simply needed to add '.;' at the end of the path link at the PATH.
Cheers

Comment: @mcalex, It's about PATH, not CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message clearly states, Eclipse cannot find the entire JVM.

Add the directory that contains `javaw.exe` to your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Better to add `JAVA_HOME` as a new system variable in the same screen where you see the class path by clicking `New` and providing the folder location for JAVA root installation folder e.g. below:

```
    Variable Name= JAVA_HOME
    Variable Value= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09
```